# Создание реквизита со ссылкой на другой объект конфигурации 1С

Tags: 1с

Как создать реквизит в объекте конфигурации "Документ" со ссылкой на реквизит из другого справочника 1С?

Я хочу взять из данного реквизита (Выделено в первом изображении):
[image: Текст]

Далее создать реквизит со ссылкой на этот реквизит из справочника в самом документе
(Выделен планируемый созданный реквизит):

[image: Текст]

Comment: Судья заносится как тренер? Если да, то зачем тут этот атрибут?

Answer (score 0):

Указать в реквизите "Квалификация" табличной части "Судейская бригада" документа такой же тип, какой у реквизита справочника.

> Как создать реквизит в объекте конфигурации "Документ" со ссылкой на
> реквизит из другого справочника 1С?

В 1С напрямую таких связей нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, Вам не нужно хранить квалификацию тренера в документе, но нужно отражать квалификацию в форме документа. Это не требует хранения реквизита в документе, но требует донастройки формы документа. В зависимости от режима 1С — обычное приложение (обычные формы) или управляемое приложение (управляемые формы) код на форме документа будет разным. Если это обычное приложение, то заполнение производится в процедуре "ПриПолученииДанных" таблицы формы. Если управляемое, то проще — просто добавляете реквизит в таблицу и указываете источник данных — Тренер.Квалификация